# FinderSync extension and Main app: notifications from extension are ignored

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode13, findersync

I'm trying to make a FinderSync extension that should add menu items and post notifications about clicks and the Main app that should react on clicks.

Right now I have two targets, both with same app groups in their entitlements:

- `FinderMenu` - the main app, Not Sandboxed
- `FinderMenuExtension` - the extension, Sandboxed.

Although when I use `DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(...)` from the extension, the main app doesn't get it.

No reaction at all!

I googled around, and it appears that same app group for both targets should be all what's needed. But it just doesn't work.

MacOS: 12.3, Xcode: 13.4.1.

Here's the repo FWIW: https://github.com/iliakan/finder-menu

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe I found the solution.

I changed all groups to `group.com....` instead of just `com....` and enabled signing with development certificate (logged into xcode with my apple id).

Plus, it seems that the observer only triggers when the app is activated.